# Generic Type in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inversion-of-control

I have a Generic Type Interface and want a constructor of an object to take in the Generic Interface.
Like:

```
public Constructor(int blah, IGenericType<T> instance)
{}
```

I want the code that creates this object to specify the IGenericType (use Inversion of Control).  I have not seen a way for this to happen.  Any suggestions to accomplish this?

I want someone to create the object like:

```
Constructor varname = new Constructor(1, new GenericType<int>());
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can't make constructors generic, but you can use a generic static method instead:

```
public static Constructor CreateInstance<T>(int blah, IGenericType<T> instance)
```

and then do whatever you need to after the constructor, if required. Another alternative in some cases might be to introduce a non-generic interface which the generic interface extends.

EDIT: As per the comments...

If you want to save the argument into the newly created object, and you want to do so in a strongly typed way, then the type must be generic as well.

At that point the constructor problem goes away, but you *may* want to keep a static generic method anyway in a non-generic type: so you can take advantage of type inference:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static Foo<T> CreateInstance<T>(IGenericType<T> instance)
    {
        return new Foo<T>(instance);
    }
}

public class Foo<T>
{
    public Foo(IGenericType<T> instance)
    {
        // Whatever
    }
}

...

IGenericType<string> x = new GenericType<string>();
Foo<string> noInference = new Foo<string>(x);
Foo<string> withInference = Foo.CreateInstance(x);
```

Comment: I would like to save the IGenericType as a member var, to do that I guess I would have to make the whole class generic not just the method...?

Comment: Yes, if you need it to be strongly typed as a member variable, then you should make the whole type generic and then the constructor problem goes away.

Comment: would like to run my design idea by you to see if there is something fundamentally better to do.  Dont think I can type it all in this comment.  Can I post to your blog or email you?

Comment: Unfortunately, generic static methods don't allow to use object initializers.  This fails to compile: Foo.CreateInstance(x) { Prop = "42" };

Comment: @Bruno: Indeed... that's definitely unfortunate :(

Comment: @JonSkeet What is this IGenericType you guys are talking about? I am running a old version of .net and it is not included (i think)?

Comment: @jordan.peoples: It's not any specific type - it's just an example of a generic interface, with a concrete implementation of `GenericType<T>`.

Comment: "You can't make constructors generic" - But why not(?) - Is the real question here... does this mean that every Form which depends on Generics as parameters needs t be static O_o?!

Comment: @ChenChi: I'm afraid I don't understand your comment at all, or whether it's specific to forms. I suggest you ask a more detailed new question.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yea it's specific to forms... I was trying to make a "DataGridView Form" which has IEnumerable<T> dataSource as a parameter in constructor...sry for almost off-topic comment but I don't quite understand your solution in the context of Form constructors

Comment: @JonSkeet I wrote about my problem here: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341432/how-should-i-implement-generic-datagrid-for-crud-operations

Comment: @ChenChi: That doesn't look like a very specific question at the moment... (And a DataGrid isn't a Form...)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: well I know that DataGrid isn't a form, but if I used a Form specifically for DataGridView I call it "DataGridView Form"... to make it more specific my problem was making a constructor which has Generic type as a parameter in my case "IEnumerable<T> dataSource"

Comment: @ChenChi: Sorry, but comment threads really aren't meant to be for discussion like this. Please ask a much more specific question here on SO.

Comment: The static function requires the generic type on the name too: **public static Foo<T> CreateInstance<T>(IGenericType<T> instance){...}**