# Initialize a non-generic object with a generic object

Tags: c#, wcf, generics, constructor

Sometimes I do not get those `T`s of C# Generics right. I have a generic struct

```
public struct ValueWithUnit<T>
{
    public ValueWithUnit(T _value, Unit _unit)
    {
        Unit = _unit;
        Value = _value;
    }
    public Unit Unit { get; }
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

(`Unit`is an `enum`, `T` should be numeric, but there is no constraint available for that purpose).

For WCF I need a non-generic version of that, with `T` being `double`. So I thought of:

```
public struct DoubleValueWithUnit 
{
    public DoubleValueWithUnit(double _value, Unit _unit)
    {
        Unit = _unit;
        Value = _value;
    }
    public DoubleValueWithUnit(ValueWithUnit<T> _valueWithUnit)
    {
        Unit = _valueWithUnit.Unit;
        Value = Convert.ToDouble(_valueWithUnit.Value);
    }
    public Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

But the second constructor does not compile: 
`error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found ...` and Convert.ToDouble complains with
`Cannot resolve method 'ToDouble(T)' Candidates are...`

I know I can add a conversion method to the generic class:

```
    public DoubleValueWithUnit ToDoubleValueWithUnit()
    {
        return new DoubleValueWithUnit(Convert.ToDouble(Value), Unit);
    }
```

That works. But is there any possibility to add a constructor with a generic parameter to a non-generic class/struct?

Comment: Why don't you just use `ValueWithUnit<double>` instead of `DoubleValueWithUnit`?

Comment: What you're trying to do [isn't possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700966/generic-type-in-constructor) - however, Maarten's advice is probably the best solution here

Comment: @Maarten because of WCF's compatibility with generics...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this constructor should exist at all:

```
public DoubleValueWithUnit(ValueWithUnit<T> _valueWithUnit)
{
    Unit = _valueWithUnit.Unit;
    Value = Convert.ToDouble(_valueWithUnit.Value);
}
```

Why do you want to convert a `ValueWithUnit<T>` to a `DoubleValueWithUnit`? With some values of `T`, this does not make sense. How do you convert a `BinaryFormatter` to `double`? Or a `Form` to `double`? These simply should not be allowed at compile time.

So you either do this:

```
public DoubleValueWithUnit(ValueWithUnit<double> _valueWithUnit)
{
    Unit = _valueWithUnit.Unit;
    Value = _valueWithUnit.Value;
}
```

Or remove the constructor all together.

Comment: "Why do you want to convert" - WCF does not cope with generics. "T" is de facto numeric, but there is no `where T : numeric`  available.

Comment: @BernhardHiller I see. Then I suggest you to write a constructor for every numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, T is simply not defined. So you cannot use T in the context of that struct.

Just remove this constructor:

```
public DoubleValueWithUnit(ValueWithUnit<T> _valueWithUnit)
```

Since you would like to convert anything passed to Double, define a constructor taking as input an object. In the constructor try to cast and throw an exception if the object is not convertible.

```
public DoubleValueWithUnit(object obj, Unit unit)
{
    Unit = unit;
    try
    {
       Value = Convert.ToDouble( obj );
    }
    catch( Exception )
    {
       throw new ArgumentException("Cannot convert to double", nameof(obj) );
    }        
}
```

Comment: Throwing exception in constructor is also not a good idea... Just notifying.

Comment: @kuskmen Contracts work exactly that way. Don't mind. (what you say is not true)

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to have the struct implementing a generic interface which in turn inherits from a non-generic interface:

```
public struct ValueWithUnit<T> : IValueWithUnit<T> {...}

public interface IValueWithUnit<out T> : IValueWithUnit // where T: number
{
    new T Value { get; }
}
public interface IValueWithUnit
{
    object Value { get; }
    Unit Unit { get; }
}
```

Now, I can pass a `ValueWithUnit<T>` into the (modified) constructor:

```
public DoubleValueWithUnit(IValueWithUnit _valueWithUnit)
{
    Unit = _valueWithUnit.Unit;
    Value = Convert.ToDouble(_valueWithUnit.Value);
}
```

Still I am not sure if there are better solutions possible.