# Use generic type in abstract class constructor

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a problem similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700966/generic-type-in-constructor) but mine is a bit different.

I want to create something like this

```
public abstract class Plot
{
    protected GameObject plotModel;
    protected IDataPoint[] data;
    protected GameObject[] plotModelInstances;

    protected Plot<TDataPoint>(TDataPoint[] data, GameObject plotModel, Vector2 plotCenter = default) where TDataPoint : IDataPoint
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.plotModel = plotModel;
        plotModelInstances = new GameObject[data.Length];
        this.plotCenter = plotCenter;
    }
}
```

A base class that takes in a data array of a generic type which implements the interface IDataPoint.
The child class is now supposed to be constructed with a data array of a struct that implements this interface

```
public BarPlot(BarDataPoint[] data, GameObject plotModel, float barWidth = 1, float barHeight = 1, Vector2  = default) : base(data, plotModel, plotCenter) 
    {
        this.barWidth = barWidth;
        this.barHeight = barHeight; 
    }
```

One answer in the thread linked above said that constructors can't use generics in C# and suggested a combination of a generic class and a static class.
However, I don't want a whole class but only one parameter to be generic.
Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: Why does the constructor need to be generic? `data` is simply setting a field, so what's wrong with: `protected Plot(IDataPoint[] data, GameObject plotModel, Vector2 plotCenter = default)`?

Comment: The constructor itself can't use generics directly. Either you make the abstract class generic or you use an array of `IDataPoint` in the constructor.

Comment: because if I try to pass `BarDataPoint[]` to the `Plot` constructor it says it can't convert  `BarDataPoint[]` to  `IDataPoint[]`. But I also don't want to pass in `IDataPoint[]` into the `BarPlot` constructor since this wouldn't be the correct type

Comment: Does `BarDataPoint` implement `IDataPoint`? If it does, then there shouldn't be a problem. If it does not, generics isn't going to help anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option is probably something like this:

```
public abstract class Plot<TDataPoint>  where TDataPoint : IDataPoint
{
    protected GameObject plotModel;
    protected TDataPoint[] data; // Note: Changed IDatePoint[] to TDataPoint[]!
    protected GameObject[] plotModelInstances;

    // Note: Changed IDatePoint[] to TDataPoint[]!
    protected Plot(TDataPoint[] data, GameObject plotModel, Vector2 plotCenter = default)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.plotModel = plotModel;
        plotModelInstances = new GameObject[data.Length];
        this.plotCenter = plotCenter;
    }
}
```

And then, in the child class:

```
public class BarPlot : Plot<BarDataPoint>
{

    public BarPlot(BarDataPoint[] data, GameObject plotModel, float barWidth = 1, float barHeight = 1, Vector2  = default) 
        : base(data, plotModel, plotCenter) 
    {
        this.barWidth = barWidth;
        this.barHeight = barHeight; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to help :-)